# My buttons sit side by side in my Home window but they appear in the middle. How do I get them higher up?

Tags: python, user-interface, mobile, tkinter, tk-toolkit

[image]

I am having a similar issue with the Shop class too. My first button (Teapops) is where I want all my buttons on my Home window and Shop window to be (except for Back to Home) if I use:

```
      button1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=10, pady=60, expand=NO)
      button2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=30, pady=60, expand=NO)
      button3.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=60, pady=60, expand=NO)
```

[image]

But then all the others appear lower and lower and I don't have any idea why except maybe I have an issue with my frames?

If I use this,

```
      button1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
      button2.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
      button3.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

then all my buttons appear side by side but in the middle of the screen again like on my Home screen:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me whats going on? I think there are some basics about Frames that I am not understanding. Please help!!!!

```
import Tkinter as tk   
from Tkinter import *

TITLE_FONT = (“Helvetica”, 18, “bold”)
CREDITS_FONT = (“Helvetica”, 12, “bold”)

class App(tk.Tk):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

      container = tk.Frame(self)
      container.pack(side=“top”, fill=“both”, expand=True)
      container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
      container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

     self.frames = {}
      for F in (Home, My_Plnts, Jrnl, Shop, Mail):
          page_name = F.__name__
          frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
          self.frames[page_name] = frame

          frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=“nsew”)

      self.show_frame(“Home”)

  def show_frame(self, page_name):

      frame = self.frames[page_name]
      frame.tkraise()

class Home(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.controller = controller

      Home.configure(self, background=’#ade5ad’)

      label = tk.Label(self, text=“Welcome Home, Maebert!”, background=’#ade5ad’, font=TITLE_FONT)
      label.pack(side=“top”, fill=“x”, pady=10)

      button1 = tk.Button(self, text=“My Plnts”,
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“My_Plnts”))
      button2 = tk.Button(self, text=“Jrnl”,
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Jrnl”))
      button3 = tk.Button(self, text=“Shop”,
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Shop”))
      button4 = tk.Button(self, text=“Mail”,
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Mail”))
      button1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=60)
      button2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=60)
      button3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=60)
      button4.pack(side=LEFT, padx=60)

class My_Plnts(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.controller = controller

      My_Plnts.configure(self, background=’#ade5ad’)

      label = tk.Label(self, text=“My Plnts”, background=’#ade5ad’, font=TITLE_FONT)
      label.pack(side=“top”, anchor=NW, fill=“x”, pady=10)
      button = tk.Button(self, text=“Back to Home”,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Home”))
      button.pack(side=“top”, anchor=NE)

class Jrnl(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.controller = controller

      Jrnl.configure(self, background=’#ade5ad’)

      label = tk.Label(self, text=“Jrnl”, background=’#ade5ad’, font=TITLE_FONT)
      label.pack(side=“top”, fill=“x”, pady=10)
      button = tk.Button(self, text=“Back to Home”,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Home”))
      button.pack(side=“top”, anchor=NE)

class Shop(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.controller = controller

      Shop.configure(self, background=’#ade5ad’)

      label = tk.Label(self, text=“Shop”, background=’#ade5ad’, font=TITLE_FONT)
      label.pack(side=“top”, fill=“x”, pady=10)

      label = tk.Label(self, text=“More at www.gfc.com”, background=’#ade5ad’, font=CREDITS_FONT)
      label.pack(side=“bottom”, fill=“x”, pady=10)

      button = tk.Button(self, text=“Back to Home”,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Home”))

      button1 = tk.Button(self, text=“Teapops”,
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Teapops”))
      button2 = tk.Button(self, text=“Plants”,
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Plants”))
      button3 = tk.Button(self, text=“Nail Polish”,
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Nail_Polish”))

      button.pack(side=“top”, anchor=NE)

      button1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
      button2.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
      button3.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

      “”“
      button1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=10, pady=60, expand=NO)
      button2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=30, pady=60, expand=NO)
      button3.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=60, pady=60, expand=NO)
”“”

class Mail(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.controller = controller

      Mail.configure(self, background=’#ade5ad’)

      label = tk.Label(self, text=“Mail”, background=’#ade5ad’, font=TITLE_FONT)
      label.pack(side=“top”, fill=“x”, pady=10)
      button = tk.Button(self, text=“Back to Home”,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“Home”))
      button.pack(side=“top”, anchor=NE)

if __name__ == “__main__”:
  app = App()
  app.minsize(300,300)
  app.geometry(“800x800”)
  app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am not sure what is going on with your quote mark but when I copy your code all of you quote marks are the wrong characters. They are `“ ”` instead of being `" "` and `’` instead of `'`

Comment: Taking a look at your code you are trying to use `container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`. These are eventually doing nothing because you are using `pack()` and the grid row/column configure for weights only works with the `grid()` geometry manager.

Comment: Maybe it's because I used """ """ to disable a few lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built the below program to demonstrate to you how the `.pack()` method works, please feel free to play around with the different options and see how each affects the output:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top = Toplevel()
top.withdraw()
var1 = StringVar(root)
var1.set("top")
var2 = StringVar(root)
var2.set("none")
var4 = StringVar(root)
var4.set("center")
var3 = BooleanVar(root)

def command(top, var1, var3, var2):
    top.destroy()
    top = Toplevel()
    top.geometry("500x500")
    Label(top, text="Welcome home").pack()
    Button(top, text="Button1").pack(side=var1.get(), fill=var2.get(), expand=var3.get(), anchor=var4.get())
    Button(top, text="Button2").pack(side=var1.get(), fill=var2.get(), expand=var3.get(), anchor=var4.get())
    Button(top, text="Button3").pack(side=var1.get(), fill=var2.get(), expand=var3.get(), anchor=var4.get())
    Button(top, text="Button4").pack(side=var1.get(), fill=var2.get(), expand=var3.get(), anchor=var4.get())

option1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, "top", "left", "bottom", "right")
check1 = Checkbutton(root, variable=var3, text="Expand?")
option2 = OptionMenu(root, var2, "none", "x", "y", "both")
option3 = OptionMenu(root, var4, "center", "n", "ne", "e", "se", "s", "sw", "w", "nw")
button1 = Button(root, text="Render", command=lambda:command(top, var1, var3, var2))

option1.pack()
check1.pack()
option2.pack()
option3.pack()
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This should show you how the different options affect the results of the `.pack()`.

More to the point I believe the effect you are looking for can be achieved using `.pack(side="left", expand="true", fill="x", anchor="n")`.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: And the program you built for me definitely helped me understand how to use pack better. You must be so advanced :3 I'm jealous